# Postgres array using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am calling a store procedure from postgres which takes an array as one of the parameters

```
cursor.execute('select * from "public"."GetPendingEmails"(%s)',(emailsubject,))
emailresults = cursor.fetchall()


for emaildata in emailresults:
    htmlbody = emaildata[0]
    toemail = emaildata[1]
    ccemail = emaildata[2]



ccemail = ccemail.split(',')
toemail = toemail.split(',')

 cursor.callproc('public."notification"(%(p_source)s,%(p_toAddress)s::[],%(p_fromAddress)s, %(p_subject)s, %(p_body)s, %(p_mailFormat)s, %(p_mailPriority)s, %(p_ccAddress)s::[]);' ,(emailsource,toemail, emailfrom, emailsubject, htmlbody, emailformat, emailpriority, ccemail))
```

ccemail is in the following format: ['email1@test.com', 'email2@test.com']

I am getting this error when i call cursor.callproc.  I am passing
ccemail.  In the database, this is an array parameter

```
      TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: which line is causing this issue?

Comment: i get the error at cursor.callproc with the ccemail that i am passing

Answer (score 0):

You are using placeholders like %(foo)s, which is what you’d use if your values were in a dictionary, but your values are in a tuple, so you need to use integer indices (or just %s, if everything is already in the right order).

Comment: I'm using  %(foo)s because i have some parameters that are optional which I don't need to call.  Sorry for the beginner question but how do i use integer indices?  do you have an example?  I tried setting it to a dictionary and then did [0], but i got the same error.